# File policy-rc.d in WSL1 not found

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, udev

I am trying to resolve the udev issue in my WSL, and I am following the ["Apt-get upgrade errors" troubleshooting steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#apt-get-upgrade-errors) in the WSL docs.

> To fix issues related to udev, follow the following steps:
>
> 1. Write the following to `/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d` and save your changes.
>
>    ```
>    #!/bin/sh
>    exit 101
>    ```
> 2. Add execute permissions to `/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d`:
>
>    ```
>    chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
>    ```
> 3. Run the following commands:
>
>    ```
>    dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
>    ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
>    ```

However it seems that the file `policy-rc.d` does not exist yet?

Is it missing or do I need to create it? As this is not complete clear for me from the documentation? I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file doesn't exist, just create it. Note that the steps include adding execute permission to the file, but an existing script file in `/usr/sbin` would likely already have execute permissions, so the presence of that step implies that the file probably wouldn't already exist.